# Link that automatically starts zip file download?

Tags: download, zip

I've seen sites where they link to files, and when clicked it begins thendownload of that zip. How would I go about creating that in my tumblr blog, if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can zip and upload the files ;). In most cases, where it needs to be done, its probably done server side and stored for use - so no, you can't do that easily with tumblr.

Comment: How about wordpress?

Comment: if its automatically zipped, it needs to be done server side.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you need is on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer).

Tumblr may not allow the use of <iframe> tags though

Comment: That helps, but I'm running firefox, which is great, but where do I put the file online so I even have a URL to enter?

Comment: Can you not upload them to Tumblr?  I'm afraid I don't use it so can't offer any more help.  If not, there are lots of online file hosting sites, but you are specifically going to need one that allows you to share your files publicly and give a direct link to the file.  FileDen (http://www.fileden.com/) seems to do this, but the free accounts expire after 60 days inactivity, so it may be a bit of a pain.  You might want to try asking for a suitable hosting service on the StackExchange Web Apps site (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).